# How to know when clicked on currently active tab item wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Assume there are `tab1` and `tab2` as two tab items and currently active tab is `tab1`. `SelectedIndex` Property set is only called when there is a change in SelectedIndex. I want an which executes even on currently active tab. `MouseDown` event is not working on tab item.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Explicitly register the MouseDown event on the tabitem

Comment: Bind to ItemsSource and SelectedItem. Drop the first tab model into SelectedItem at startup. Watch the property and act on change. Tada.

Comment: @Will , I think SelectedItem will also work same as SelectedIndex

Comment: SelectedIndex sucks. Don't use it. Always use SelectedItem. And, since you drop the SelectedItem at startup, you will have "an which executes even on currently active tab".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a Tab **HeaderTemplate to handle the click**. Look at the sample code below:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="myTabHeaderTemplate">
        <!-- Handle click here -->
        <Grid MouseDown="TabControl_MouseDown">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl 
    Background="WhiteSmoke" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTab}">

    <TabItem Header="tab 1" Background="LightPink" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myTabHeaderTemplate}" />
    <TabItem Header="tab 2" Background="LightGreen" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource myTabHeaderTemplate}" />
</TabControl>
```

- **TabControl_MouseDown()** will be invoked even if your tab is already selected

You have to implement this method in code behind:

```
private void TabControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e){ ... }
```

Or you can bind it to a command in your ViewModel...